# Storyboard is taking more time to load

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

Im using Xcode 9.2,Im working in a static tableViewController with the height of almost 1500.When I open that storyboard it is taking more time to load, sometimes it is not opening.So it is very hard for development.I have tried to open this in Xcode 9 and 8 versions.But samething is happened.Any Solution for this?

Comment: Cant you just separate each cell to their own Xib? It create many files but load faster

Comment: Better you can go with creating table view cells in xib file(this will help you to reduce your tableViewController height). Reduce your tableViewController height if your storyboard loaded at least for one time.

Comment: yes thats what I'm going to do now,But I just want a reason why the storyboard is taking too much time to load?

Answer (score 1):

Open a new Window from the Storyboard and minimize it. So it stays in RAM and won't reload. Working with the storyboard keeps quick and easy now.

This new Window may automatic refresh your build every time while coding for that Do below solution:
 For this goto Storyboard -> Menu Editor -> Automatically Refresh View just uncheck it .

Along with 
Please do this step:

Go to Preferences -> General and disable Live Issues in Editors and in Issue Navigator
[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution, but the storyBoard in the Xcode is not showing sections, rows,textfields,labels.It is just showing an empty UI

Comment: try cmd+shif+K also try cmd+alt+shift+k , it will clear your derive  Data